# Package PHP Code for Distribution

Tags: java, php, jar, package, phar

I know there is a lot difference between PHP and Java. My requirement is to package the PHP code so that it can be distributed to the customers.

I am planning a PHP application which can be packaged to the customers and can be installed at their end. I am looking for a possibility to hide my source code from the customer. Like JAR file in Java. I know we can have PHAR file, but that again doesn't solve the complete problem. You cannot package very big application into a PHAR file.

While using PHAR file, the only solution is to package small libraries and keep rest things intact.

Is there any other way to acheive this use case?

Comment: You may want to look at a tool called Zend Guard: http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard. I have no affiliation with Zend or that product, and I've never actually used it before (although I have used other Zend products). I just know it exists and it sounds like it might be adequate for what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good alternative will be ionCube, its not a packer but it can encode your Source and hide it in this way.

[ionCube](https://www.ioncube.com/)

Comment: ionCube also have a package foundry product that can create windows installers to remotely deploy a web application to a remote server. You can also create the windows installer using Linux, which is useful for automation. One downside is that the installers cannot be signed though.
Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.